# How python del operator works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, del

I tried to understand how del() works in python. I recognized that it deletes only the identifier or reference. Then, the del() operator does not clear the memory and how it works?

```
import _ctypes
o=8667747
i=id(o) 
del o
print(_ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(i)) #8667747
```

Comment: `del` removes the reference like you said. If this results in no more references to that object, the object will eventually be garbage collected & the memory freed by the python runtime.

Comment: then,which time it clear the memory(garbage collector)?

Comment: That's upto the runtime that you're using. Usually you wouldn't need to bother with that. See [this](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) for more info. If you need to call the garbage collector manually (not recommended) see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)

Comment: @Janith Python has automatic memory management. The CPython runtime uses reference counting, in which case, when a reference count goes to 0, the object is immediately reclaimed (the memory returned to the privately managed heap). Additionally, an auxiliary cyclic garbage collector deals with reference cycles, which happens periodically and can be controlled by the `gc` module. `del` *does not delete objects*. Objects will be free to be garbage collected when they are no longer referenced, and `del` deletes *references*.

Comment: IOW, python is like Java, not like C/C++ You would use `del` for the same reason you might use `someVar = null;` in Java to make sure a reference to an object is removed. Of course, in Python, you can also effectively do `some_var = None`

Comment: but,I think None is a data type in python

Comment: Another complication is that `8667747` is stored in the `co_consts` of the code object and thus will never actually be garbage collected. If you add something like `for x in range(10000): o += x` so that it's no longer seen as a constant then things change a bit but I'm having trouble creating a consistently reproducible example. At this point you're entering undefined behaviour territory and the version of Python used makes a difference.

Comment: @Janith yes, it is. Python is purely object oriented, *everything* is an object with a type.